# Managing backstack order with non-fragment elements

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am at a loss of what to do. The general layout of my application is everything is contained within a single activity. In this activity a primary fragment is loaded. This primary fragment has a search view which can filter results. By clicking items in the primary fragment another secondary fragment is loaded as a dialog. At any point the user may click a link adding another primary fragment onto the stack. My problem is when a user is pressing back to move up the backstack the searchview will take priority over the secondary fragments and remove the users filtered data.

Here is ideally what I want for my backstack order

```
Activity -> primary Fragment -> searchview filter -> secondary fragments * X -> primary fragment -> repeat
```

Here is my current backstack order

```
Activity -> primary fragment -> secondary fragments * X -> searchview filter -> primary fragment -> repeat
```

Current onBackPressed() located in the activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
   if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
       getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
   } else {
       this.finish();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the filtered search results, you override `onSaveInstanceState()` and save the filter constraint.  In your `onCreateView()` override, you check if `savedInstanceState` is not null and if it is, you get the filter constraint from that and re-filter the results.